# Open UIViewController, don't show UINavigationController navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have Navigation controller from my views.

[image]

In my View Controller have a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method with a switch. In first cell I want to open my new view "Empresa", I use this:

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Empresa")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And work, but not apear navigation controller. View apear like this:

[image]

Comment: use `pushViewController` instead `presentViewController`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this place

```
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**update**

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Empresa") as yourviewcontrollerName
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ArisGuimerá you can mark it as the correct answer if it helped

Comment: @marosoaie, for sure, I have to wait 10 min to mark ^^